# Adding sortable column from another tables in datatables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, jquery-datatables-rails

```
Rails 5.2
datatables
```

I am following a mini tutorial, on implementing databables with Rails. The table

```
 class BlogDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::ActiveRecord

  def view_columns
    @view_columns ||= {
      id:          { source: "Blog.id" },
      user:        { source: "Blog.user_id"}
      title:       { source: "Blog.title" },
    }
  end

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      {
          id:          record.id,
          title:       record.title,
          DT_RowId:    record.id,
      }
    end
  end

  def get_raw_records
    Blog.all
  end

end
```

What I really want to display for the column user, is the user email, but the user email is in the table Users. How do I implement this with datatables, and stil be able to do sorting, based on the email, not the user_id that's in the blogs table?

Comment: You have a better option to implement the Datatable using json and jbuilder in rails

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan Would you be able to expand on that?

Comment: I assume you need a datatable about about blogs and you need it on Blogs index page...is it??

Comment: Yes, this will be for the index view

Comment: did you installed `gem 'jquery-datatables'` ??

Comment: Yes, gem "jquery-datatables" and gem 'ajax-datatables-rails' are instsalled

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

Assuming you have the routes set to `resources: blogs`

Your table in the `index.html.erb` will be

```
<table class="responsive nowrap table table-hover" id="dttb-blogs" data-sort="true" data-source="<%= url_for(format: :json)%>">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th data-data="title">Title</th>
   <th data-data="user_email">User</th>
   <th data-data="url" data-orderable="false" data-class-name="all" data-searchable="false" class="skip-export" width="100px"></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Add `_blog.json.jbuilder` in blogs

```
json.extract! blog, :id, :title, :user_id, :created_at, :updated_at
json.user_email blog.user.email
json.url blog_url(blog, format: :json)
```

Add `index.json.jbuilder` in blogs

```
json.set! :data do
json.array! @blogs do |blog|
json.partial! 'blogs/blog', blog: blog
json.url  "
          #{link_to 'Show', blog }
          #{link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog)}
          #{link_to 'Destroy', blog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }}
          "
end
end
```

This will create the datatable using json object by taking the @blogs instance variable from your index action

and for your question how to show email in the user column which is in the user table, Assuming you have referenced the user table with blogs table, 
ie

in your blogs model 
you should have an association:

```
belongs_to :user
```

now you wil get the user email by `blog.user.email`

Comment: Why would I do all this, when I can do: render json: { data: @blogdata } from the controller method